# Number formatting

Tags: php, html, numbers, whitespace

In my database I have the following numeric values:

```
1000
1500
10000
12500
100000
890000
1000000
6900000
```

On the frontend I would like to display these numbers like:

```
1 000
1 500
10 000
12 500
100 000
890 000
1 000 000
6 900 000
```

What would be the best way to achive this?

I have tried something like:

```
function convert_number($number) {
   $string = "".$number."";
   $count = strlen($string);
   $result = '';
   for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      $result .= $string[$i];
      if(($i % 4) == 0) $result .= ' ';
   }
   return $result;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't the built-in `number_format()` function do what you want? The title of your question is practically the answer.

Comment: @Barmar - wow, never heard about that function. Seems to do exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KristerAndersson: Please always search before asking. Searching in Google for "number formatting" would have listed the function :)

Comment: @AmalMurali - I did, I looked for something like `number whitespaces formatting html` and so on.

Comment: Perhaps I should have looked harder before asking this question=) The `number_format()` saved my day, thank you very much. Stackoverflow rules.

Comment: I think front end should be done with javascript. Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809136/how-to-format-numbers-with-white-spaces-between-thousands

Comment: @Benedictus - That will be very useable too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use PHP's [number_format](http://php.net/number_format):

```
echo number_format( $number, null, null, ' ' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use number_format() function of php

```
number_format(1000, 0, '', ' ');
```

this will o/p
1 000

ref: http://php.net/number_format